# c++ Random unexplained error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl, kinect, openni

I'm creating a kinect project in Visual Studio 2008 using OpenNi, NITE and OpenGL.

At random times dureing development I get the following error:

> Error result 1 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\rc.exe'.

I've searched the internet with no luck.

I am able to create a new project and copy all my code across and it works fine but this is not something I want to be doing multiple times each day.

If any more info is required I'd be happy to give it.

EDIT full output window reads

```
1>------ Build started: Project: PointViewer, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling resources...
1>Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
1>Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>fatal error RC1110: could not open ..\Res\NITE.rc
1>Project : error PRJ0002 : Error result 1 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\rc.exe'.
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\Documents\Uni work\Year 4\Personal Project\Samples \PointViewer\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>PointViewer - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Anything special about the .rc files (resource files) that it's trying to compile?

Comment: So you're saying that once this error occurs it 'sticks' and that to work around it you have to create a new project? Stopping/starting Visual Studio doesn't clear the problem?

Comment: Have you seen http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/feeda646-4ba8-497d-b9d1-c9e2eca62961#83aaceb5-8818-4e38-9407-a96b77607133? (Found by Googling `"error result 1 returned from" "rc.exe"`.)

Comment: Logging what`rc.exe` does using Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) might help figure out what's going on.

Comment: To my knowledge there is nothing special. The rc file I'm using was included with the NITE framework that I'm using as I'm building my program from one of their samples.

Comment: I really believe there is an error message being returned just before that final "Error result."  Be sure you are looking at the full output, not just the "errors and warnings window".  The lines leading up to the final error should tell you what is going wrong.  Post full output of your build-step here.

Comment: @ruakh Any chance you know where those options are on windows 7? Can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing your RC file via a relative path (`..`).
It seems likely your current directory is changing, and hence `..`, and the path to your RC file changes, causing the error.

You will have to make sure that your RC file is referred to in a way that doesn't change.
Try removing it from the project, and re-adding it, taking care to refer to it only in absolute terms.

Check your project and build settings for the directory where the build is to start, and how the filename is preserved in the project settings.  You're looking for something like "Persist Filenames As...".

Comment: You're absolutely right. What I dont understand though is why it worked for a while after I moved my project. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Move your entire project folder into documents/visualstudio/projects. If that doesn't work, move it to your desktop.  It is just a linking problem, it can't find the resources. Make sure you aren't moving your folders around as this can cause these issues.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for the error described - .rc file was renamed. 
Check the .rc file name in your .vcproj file and see that it actually exists on disk.